# issue with gradle andriod

Tags: java, android, windows, gradle

### Launching lib\main.dart on SM A127F in debug mode... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\Online Sports Fitness Code 31 Dec\Online Spo rts Fitness\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'. at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.(WrapperExecutor.java:64) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:47) at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:60) Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 60: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2913) at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3084) at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3166) at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3114) at java.base/java.net.URI.(URI.java:600) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:81) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExec at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java :81) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExec utor.java:70) at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.(WrapperExecutor.java:57) ... 2 more Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... 1,478ms Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 getting this error

Answer (score 1):

The distributionUrl should be like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Note: **You will need to escape the colon**.

Comment: Not working @navylover

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the whole content of **gradle-wrapper.properties** with this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

And after this, do a fresh gradle sync.
Also, check if your AGP is on latest version or not.

Comment: not working @sujal kumar